# Attribute parent dynamically to a QML component based in a condition

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

How to attribute a parent dynamically when the QML component is being created  based in a condition?

Example:

//FirstFile.qml

```
SecondFile{

  Rectangle {
    id: bodyRect

  }    
}
```

//SecondFile.qml

```
Rectangle{
  id: rectangleId

  Flickable{
    id: flickableId

  }    
}
```

In this example the parent of `bodyRect` is `rectangleId`.

How to attribute the `flickableId` as a parent of `bodyRect`if a condition is true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it really depends on what you actually want to achieve, which is totally unclear from the question as it stands right now.

If you use dynamic object instantiation, you can simply pass the desired parent to the function:

```
someComponent.createObject(condition ? parent1 : parent2)
```

Additionally, you can change the visual parent of an object based on a condition:

```
  property bool cond: false

  property Rectangle rect: Rectangle {
    Rectangle {
      parent: cond ? redrect : bluerect
      anchors.centerIn: parent
      width: 50
      height: 50
      color: "blue"
    }
  }

  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: cond = !cond
  }

  Row {
    Rectangle {
      id: redrect
      width: 200
      height: 200
      color: "red"
    }
    Rectangle {
      id: bluerect
      width: 200
      height: 200
      color: "green"
    }
  }
```

The blue rectangle will be dynamically reparented to either the red or the green rectangle as `cond` changes.

Keep in mind that you cannot really do stuff across different files, unless the objects happen to represent actual instances that have visibility in the object tree.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's what I was looking for.